# Should I attach a current limiter to my jerry-rigged power supply?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

So, I have an old transformer style power supply rated for: "16V AC nominal 1A" and I basically just shoved in a full bridge rectifier and a cheap ebay DC-DC switching buck converter so I could use it for electronics projects.

What I would like to know is that, if I attach something that uses a lot of current (e.g. a Peltier device) is there a risk of overheating and shorting out the wires in the transformer if it uses more than the 1A listed on the transformer? If it does, should I add a current limiter or does AC amperage and DC amperage mean different values like how it does with voltage?

Thank you for your time and apologies if this has been asked before.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to have a variable current limit capability on a power supply used to power various projects. There are probably other useful protections to add, as well. But that one alone is worth some trouble. But I'm not sure why you aren't just buying a completed supply for your projects. Is it for the learning experiences?

Comment: It was originally for a learning experience but when I originally moved my project from my breadboard to a perf board and it didn't work I basically gave up and threw in a buck converter board I got from ebay.

As for why I don't just buy a normal bench power supply is cost effectiveness. If I can get a working voltage and current limiting psu for $10 I don't need to spend $70+ to get the cheapest "proper" psu. Although I do figure this opinion will bite me in the ass soon enough.

Comment: I can't argue about it. An early project of mine was to design and build a power supply. And at the time, I was quite poor (had to work as a child in the berry and vegetable fields just to survive.) So I could NOT afford any cash outlay. So I asked permission and then rummaged dumpsters to get parts. It's just that things are so much easier these days, in this regard. So I had to ask. I do think it is a great way to learn. And so I think you should add the current limiter.

Comment: Fortunately, I don't have to go through what you did. In regards to the current limiter. Does it have to be a 1 amp limit or is AC amperage different to DC amperage (I would think not but just checking. I'm more of a software person). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you'd attempt to limit the current *after* the bridge and filter capacitors (which you should be using even with an ebay DC-DC converter.) So it would be on the DC side of things. However, you need to write a LOT MORE about what you'd like to achieve. If you want to keep the DC-DC ebay item and use it to set the voltage (some include current limit, some don't, so I assume yours does NOT), then the current limit could be added after that. But it would require voltage "head room" and this mostly makes it useless. So you need to do an actual *design* and dump the ebay piece, probably.

Comment: Yes, you protect a transformer from overheating and possible ignition with a fuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does AC amperage and DC amperage mean different values like how it
>   does with voltage?

Yes. A transformer rated for 1A AC may not be able to deliver 1A DC through a rectifier and filter capacitor. The main reason for this is that the current is drawn in pulses as it charges up the capacitor, so the heating effect in the transformer windings will be higher than for a purely resistive load. In technical terms the '[crest factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_factor)' is higher, so the rms current (and loss in the winding resistance) is greater.

On the other hand, the DC/DC converter will draw less current from the supply when set for lower output voltage, since it 'transforms' the power from high voltage at low current to lower voltage at higher current.

If the filter capacitor is not big enough to hold the rectified voltage above the minimum that the converter needs to operate then its output voltage will drop and limit current. A much larger capacitor will hold the voltage up better between peaks so the converter will draw less current for the same output current, but the pulses will be shorter so the rms transformer current may be higher.

So how much current you can get out of the converter without overheating the transformer depends on its output voltage and (to a lesser extent) the value of your filter capacitor.

Here is an example simulation of a 16VAC transformer with bridge rectifier and 1000uF filter capacitor feeding a high quality DC/DC converter which is delivering 12V at 1A to a 12Ω resistive load. (blue = filter capacitor voltage, red = transformer current, green = DC/DC output voltage). The peak transformer secondary current is 3A, and the rms current is 1.3A. In comparison, if a 12VAC transformer was powering that same load directly the (AC) current would be 1.4A peak and 1A rms.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use a DC-DC on the output, these will most likely have a current limit.

If it's one of the $0.99 ones though, the "current limit" may involve a puff of smoke...

At least put a fuse on the primary, slow-blow with proper current rating.

If you want to power a 12V Peltier, a 12V wall wart of proper current rating would be a more practical solution...